# Does this jQuery voting plugin violate Stack Exchange's intellectual property rights?

Tags: discussion, design, user-interface

I'm developing a website where I want a widget similar to what is used on the Stack Exchange sites for upvoting and downvoting.

I found http://janosgyerik.github.io/jquery-upvote/.

Is it illegal if I use this? Does Stack Exchange have any patents on this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

No, Stack Exchange does not hold patents on voting (or on starring something). Voting on websites predated Stack Overflow by *years*.

However, that project's CSS design is re-using the [Stack Exchange sprites wholesale](https://github.com/janosgyerik/jquery-upvote/tree/master/lib/images), which **is** a *copyright violation*. If you use the same JS code on your site, make sure you don't reuse the CSS and images. Give the widget your own styling and you should be fine.

So, bottom line: using the idea is fine; using the design is not. That project will have to replace those sprites with images created from scratch. Stack Exchange would be well within their right if they asked that project to stop using the sprites they are using now.

Comment: Yeah, but the plugin resembles SO so much. Will there be no issues?

Comment: @AmitJoki: there are issues; with copyright.

Comment: But, if i redesign it with different colors?

Comment: If you use your own CSS and images, I see no issues.

Comment: I'm not good with images. Can you tell me where i can get?

Comment: @AmitJoki: what makes you think I am any better? :-P